# Most Searched for Keyword, in Elastic Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails

In Elastic Search, how do I get the strings that are searched for the most number of times? I tried getting this result, but was not successful.

For eg: Multiple users searches for work 'stackoverflow'. What is the total number of times, ElasticSearch has searched for the work 'stackoverflow'

or as an aggregation:

stackoverflow: 98 times
redcarpet: 40 times

...
...

Comment: Elasticsearch doesn't track this. You need to implement this functionality in your own application.

Comment: Thank you @AndreiStefan. I found this myself after a while. But thanks a lot.